# Desiging the GitLab workflow

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We are evaluating GitLab for the migration, we are currently using git (on premise) with Gerrit code review tool.
During evaulation of GitLab IAM seeing it as challenging to design the workflow for our team to adopt.

**Below is my workflow use case:**

1. Create a Branch from master
2. git commit and push to branch
3. Review by peer developers on the commited code
4. if any review comments, amend the changes and push
5. Step 3 (review by peer developers)
6. Run the tests on branch
7. Merge the commits to branch by Lead (Maintainer)
8. Deploy our dev environment using branch code
9. Merge branch to master by Maintainer

Need the suggestions what would be an ideal approach, I came across challenges like I cannot amend any changes, does GitLab supports amend?

Comment: You can do all these steps in gitlab. step 7 - what do you mean by "Merge commits to branch?"

Answer (score 0):

What you described looks fine. I added comments to steps that should be adapted to gitlab.

Your workflow could look like this:

1. ...
2. ...
3. When feature is ready for review just create `Merge Request` to merge development branch into master(or any other branch). Be aware that development branches by default are not protected on Gitlab but you can change it in project settings.
4. ...
5. ...
6. Tests can be automated e.g. with `.gitlab-ci.yml` and gitlab runners. If you have automated unit/functional/regression tests gitlab runs them after every commit. Then after creating Merge Request reviewers and feature developer has clear view besides what changes have beed done on development branch also if all tests passed. Merge Requst can be blocked by Gitlab (with proper setting in project configuration) with requirement that all test jobs pass. So I'd suggest tests are not run only in this step but after any commit automatically.
7. There is no need for this step. As developer creates branch and works on it. I understand that gerrit creates refs/for/yourDevelopmentBranch so only after patchset is approved, branch is created. There are differences between Gitlab and Gerrit so you should definately read about them to be aware of different behaviour of the two, e.g. [here](https://about.gitlab.com/devops-tools/gerrit-vs-gitlab.html).
8. You can also define it in .gitlab-ci.yml as job with `manual` trigger or just deploy changes to development environment after each commit on branch.
9. ...

Comment: Thanks a lot makozaki  for the inputs, this has given me clarity to proceed further

Answer (score 0):

**ASSUMPTIONS:**

> Only one version of code deployed to all environments
>
> Default Branch- Master- Restricted Push

- Pipeline : *

  1. Push to Feature Branch-Start--> Build-->RUN Unit tests.
  2. Merge request from feature to master --Build-->BuildDocker image-->Unit Test-->Release version and tag the code to v1.0-->DeployDev
  3. Tag code(v1.0) ---> Get the Version(from previousJob) -->DeployQA--->DeployUAT-->DeployProd (Manual Option to deploy)

if pipeline success all environments will run the version#1 code with the same docker image of version#1. Only one master branch will be the most updated one and will tag that depends on job status(success/fail).

*PIPELINE*

```
stages:
  - buildJar
  - buildImage
  - unittest
  - releaseVersion
  - deployDev
  - deployQa
  - deployUat
  - deployProd
  - cleanup
```